# Multiple index loop in Python

Tags: python, loops

I need to make several nested loops like this, but with a generic number of looping indices:

```
   for ii in range(0,num):
      for iii in range(0,num):
         for iiii in range(0,num):
            for iiiii in range(0,num):
```

Is it there any compact or practical way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am unclear what you need to do and why. Could you explain it in a bit more detail? [edit] your [mre].

Comment: use set product instead, Take a look at 'set theory' , you will find set product. you can use that to generate one list and you can iterate through that with right interval

Comment: Search for `python cartesian product`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `itertools.product` to generate tuples of the desired indices.  For example:

```
import itertools
for indices in intertools.product(range(num), repeat=depth):
    print(indices)
```

This will generate tuples of length `depth` of the values.

Here's a small example:

```
>>> for indices in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2):
...     print(indices)
... 
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
>>>
```

In this example, the number of values present in each tuple is 2, given by `repeat=2`.